# If record exist change background color from menu select html

Tags: php

Need for clarification.
I need a little script that checks if an item in my select menu exists in my table, and the script should look something like this:

```
     <?php 

 $result = mysqli_query($cn, "SELECT ora_inizio, data FROM prenotazioni WHERE ora_inizio = '$hour' and data = '$date' ");
$num_rows = mysqli_num_rows($result);

if ($num_rows > 0) {
 echo " exist";
}
else {
  // do something else
}

?>
```

My menu select is:

```
        <option value="9:00">9:00</option>
        <option value="9:15">9:15</option>
        <option value="9:30">9:30</option>
        <option value="9:45">9:45</option>
        <option value="10:00">10:00</option>
        <option value="10:15">10:15</option>
        <option value="10:30">10:30</option>
        <option value="10:45">10:45</option>
        <option value="11:00">11:00</option>
```

Now I need that if the element exists, it is colored red in the select menu.

So if record (`9:00`) exist on my table color value `9:00` on select menu.

Comment: Ok so what have you tried? Where are you stuck? Your question will be far better received if you demonstrate you made a reasonable effort to attempt this before asking others for (free) help.

Comment: There is no benefit in duplicating the text value of an option as its `value` value.  Javascript and form submissions will handle your data just fine without the `value`.

Answer (score 0):

I believe it would be better to make another table with all possible times.
Here's the complete tested script:

First create the other table:

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `oras` (
`id_ora` int NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
`ora` text COLLATE utf8mb4_general_ci NOT NULL,
PRIMARY KEY (`id_ora`)
) ENGINE=MyISAM AUTO_INCREMENT=10 DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8mb4 COLLATE=utf8mb4_general_ci;


INSERT INTO `oras` (`id_ora`, `ora`) VALUES
(1, '9:00'),
(2, '9:15'),
(3, '9:30'),
(4, '9:45'),
(5, '10:00'),
(6, '10:15'),
(7, '10:30'),
(8, '10:45'),
(9, '11:00');
```

Now the rest of the code:

```
<?php 
require("your connection file.php"); 
$date= date('Y-m-d');
$prenotazioni = $db->prepare("SELECT * FROM prenotazioni WHERE data = :data ");
$prenotazioni->bindValue(':data', $date);
$prenotazioni->execute();

$oras = $db->prepare("SELECT * FROM oras");
$oras->execute();


echo'<select name="ora">';

    while($res_oras = $oras->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)){
        $res_pre = $prenotazioni->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
        $occupied = $res_pre['ora_inizio'];


        if ($res_oras['ora'] == $occupied) {
          echo'<option value="'.$res_oras['ora'].'"  style="color:#e11313">'.$res_oras['ora'].'</option>';
        }else{
          echo'<option value="'.$res_oras['ora'].'"  >'.$res_oras['ora'].'</option>';
        }
     }
echo'</select>';

?>
```

Comment: This code could afford to be more D.R.Y.

Comment: I tried this script but if for example on the table there is already the time 9:00 it does not color it in red. It goes directly to "else" showing: <option value="9:00">9:00</option> .

Comment: Edited my answer above. Hope it helps.

Answer (score 0):

You need to prepare variable with hours:

```
$hours = ['9:00', '9:15', '9:30', '9:45', '10:00', '10:15', '10:30', '10:45', '11:00'];
```

Then You can dynamically create options like this:

```
foreach($hours as $h) {
    echo '<option value="'.$h.'"'.(($hour == $h and $num_rows) ? ' style="color:#e11313"' : '').'>'.$h.'</option>';
}
```

Database query may be as You provided. My solution is using your variable `$hour` and result from query `$num_rows`.

Comment: I tried this, but it still doesn't work. I am really desperate.                                        
    $hours = ['9:00', '9:15', '9:30', '9:45', '10:00', '10:15', '10:30', '10:45', '11:00', '11:15'];
 
 $result = mysqli_query($cn, "SELECT ora_inizio FROM prenotazioni  ");
$num_rows = mysqli_num_rows($result);


foreach($hours as $h) {
  echo '<option value="'.$h.'"'.(($hour == $h and $num_rows) ? ' style="background-color:red;"' : '').'>'.$h.'</option>';
}